# Create a shell namespace extension

Tags: c#, virtual-directory, virtual-disk

How does acronis create this virtual folders. For example I created a backup of the folder `Example` located at `C:\Example` This is how the backup looks:

[image]

**If I double click on that file then I could navigate to:**

[image]

**if I right click on that folder I will not get the regular menu that I get with directories. If I double click that directory then I will navigate to the content of that folder as:**

[image]

**Note that the content that I am looking at is inside a file not on windows explorer.**

I know that if I send VirtualDir.tib to somewone they will not be able to see the same because they do not have [acronis true image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) installed.

How could I be able to do something similar with c# ?

---

### Edit

**Sorry I just updated the title. How will I be able to create a chell namespace extension with c#?**

Comment: This is called a shell namespace extension.

Comment: Thanks I had no idea how it was called!

Comment: I guess I have a duplicate question now. I will appreciate if I could get a hellow workd example. When I google chell namespace extension the explination seems very complex...

Comment: Yes; they're very complicated.  Also, it's spelled `shell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about whether it can be done in *C#*, the answer is no. As is explicitly stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), writing shell extensions in managed code is entirely unsupported.
This is because shell extension DLLs can be loaded into multiple processes, some of which would already have another version of the CLR loaded.

Comment: This no longer applies if the namespace extension is developed using .Net 4.0, becuase .Net 4.0 supports side-by-side in-process loading. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx

Comment: logicnp: ah, I thought our recommendation for 4.0 had still been no, even with the SxS support. I'm actually not sure if Microsoft teams are consistent here...

Comment: There is no inconsistency on their part regarding .Net 4.0. Namespace extensions. Namespace extensions and shell extensions can be developed without any issue. Even with earlier versions of .Net, the issue did not apply for all circumstances. Please see http://www.ssware.com/support/viewtopic.php?t=341 which discusses this.

Comment: I thought I had read something somewhere where another Microsoft team was still saying it wasn't supported. I could be wrong.

Comment: @logicnp, that is not correct.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089(v=vs.85).aspx and related links.

Comment: This commercial product (disclaimer: I work for the company that sells it) allows you to write Shell Namespace Extension in .NET *out-of-process*: https://shellboost.com so you still follows Microsoft recommendations