# Create a web share or ftp share server

Tags: c#, windows, file-sharing

Sorry I think I am finally asking the right question. First I asked [Create a shell namespace extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341692/create-a-shell-namespace-extension)

Anyways I am synchronizing and sharing files between two peers just like drobox but with larger data. I was wondering how could I create a web share or ftp share server so that I can connect to it from windows.

For example when you click on:

[image]

**Then**

[image]

if I select `ftp://ftp.microsoft.com`

then this is what I get:

[image]

---

From researching on the internet I saw that IIS supports this. I was wondering if there are some libraries that will enable me to create this server on c#.

Comment: I'm not sure about your intention, but as i see, you have three possibilities: 1) create an smb-share (which is essentially clicking on share files in Win-Explorer), 2) create an FTP-Server with IIS or 3) create an WebDAV-Server (which is what windows calls "web Share"

All 3 can be created programatically (standalone or with iis and windows). You can buy (or perhaps theres open source) libraries for all three types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache server to do turn your computer into a hosting server. Apache comes with many software packages such as xampp, wampp which help reduce installing time.